# WPF Listbox item searching using keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a Listbox control in my XAML window which will show around 500 items at runtime.I need to navigate through this items using keyboard like Windows Explorer. For example in Windows Explorer, when we type a key **"a"**  it will automatically select an item which start with the key **a**. This will provide more usability to user. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this issue using **"TextSearch.TextPath"**. **Name** should be the property you want to navigate through the Listbox.

```
<ListBox TextSearch.TextPath="Name" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"/>
```

Comment: Can also use `TextSearch.Text="{Binding ...}"` on the individual item container. It's refactoring-safe because the binding is statically-checked.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textsearch.text?view=netframework-4.8